# Javascript refresh() method

Tags: javascript, html

Im trying to reload JUST a table on a page [Ajax it a bit confusing]

```
var table = document.getElementById ("table");
table.refresh();
```

Would that have the same results as using ajax to reload the table?

Comment: There is no such method `refresh()` on a table element in plain DOM. How would your table element know where to get its data? What *is* the source of the data? Do you need to pull it from a database? There would be no other way than AJAX to refresh your table with new data, as you probably need to do some server side processing. What technologies are you using?

Comment: Sorry, but you can't do this without ajax

Comment: Wow, I came across a site that said there was one. Ill make sure not to go there again

Comment: Cory, http://help.dottoro.com/ljpoljcl.php

Comment: Read this to get started with Ajax: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/AJAX/Getting_Started

Comment: @Alex: This seems to be some old proprietary Microsoft extension (see how it is only supported in IE?). Anyways, as the description says, this is for refreshing the style of a table, after you changed CSS rules. This has nothing to do with Ajax.

Comment: Btw, it is easier to understand Ajax if you have a basic understanding of network communication. Ajax just makes an HTTP request to the URL you provide, basically the same as if you type the URL in the browser.

Comment: Felix, im just going to have to grind through this then. Im just making a javascript to reload a table of prices without having to reload the entire page.

Answer (score 5):

There is no such JavaScript method. You are going to have to learn how to use Ajax.

You may want to look into using [jQuery](http://jquery.com/) and its [`ajax()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/) method. jQuery makes Ajax much easier to understand. Here is an example of jquery's ajax method.

```
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "pathToPage",
    data: "yourParamsToGetData",
    contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
    dataType: "json",
    success: function (result) {
        FillTableFromResults(result);
    },
    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
        if (errorThrown != null)
            alert(textStatus + " : " + errorThrown);
    }
});
```

Comment: I'm certainly not recommending iframes for this, but you *could* use an iframe to do this right? I'm still right there with you that ajax is the way to go. Maybe show a quick example for the OP?

Comment: @lbstr I have updated my answer. FYI, you could use an iframe for this, but ajax is definitely the right way to go here.